# Javascript show div does not work when I press button

Tags: javascript, button

I have this simple code, and i can't understand why it is not working.

```
<div>
    <input type="button" class="button" value="Add A Site" onclick="Div();" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Div() {
        var E = document.getElementsByClassName('Form');
        if (E.style.display == 'none') {
            E.style.display = 'block';
            this.value = "Close";
        } else {
            S.style.display = 'none';
            this.value = "Add A Site";
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="Form" style="display:none;">
    <h1>Example</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Strings should be between quotation marks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I added quotes, but it still don't work, anyway thank you for asnwer!

Comment: Learn the difference between "`=`" and "`==`" (among other things).

Comment: I don't get any error

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, which you are treating as an object. There are *many* things wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user Form which you are trying to access is inside div.form so you have to access that like below....I tested this, its working. the content in Form is displaying

```html
<input type="button" class="button" value="Add A Site"    onclick="Div();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Div() {
    var E=  document.getElementsByClassName('Form')[0];
    if (E.style.display=='none'){
      E.style.display='block';
      this.value="Close";
    }else {
      S.style.display='none';
      this.value="Add A Site";
    }
  }
</script>
<div class="Form"  style="display:none;">
    <h1>Example</h1></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   function Div() {
       var E = document.getElementsByClassName('Form')[0];
       if (E.style.display==='none') {
           E.style.display='block';
           this.value=Close;
       } else {
           E.style.display = 'none';
           this.value = 'Add A Site';
       }
   }
</script>

<input type="button" class="button" value="Add A Site" onclick="Div()" />
<div class="Form"  style="display:none;">
<h1>Example</h1>
</div>
```

This should work for you.